# How to repeat action as long I touch and when I stop touching the action stop in SpriteKit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

As said in the title I want to make an action run and repeat as long I press a button and stop and run another action when I stop touching. I don't know the method to do that so if anyone could help me with the code for example I want a sprite 
to rotate as long I press and after I stop touching move up.

```
let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1.0)
    sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))  
          let action2 = SKAction.moveToY(900, duration: 1.0)
            sprite.runAction(action2)
```

To describe exactly what I want:

> when I touch the screen an object will be created and rotate and keep rotating till I release my finger from the screen and stop touching I want it to go up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Sprite Kit scene, these methods allow you to detect when a touch begins and ends:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    // Start an action that repeats indefinitely.
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    // Remove the action after touches end.
}
```

When touches end, call `self.removeAllActions()` to stop all actions in the scene, or `sprite.removeAllActions()` to stop actions specific to a sprite.

Comment: thanks for responding can you tell me how to pass sprite between these functions ?

Comment: Declare the sprite variable outside the method as a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    sprite.removeAllActions()
    let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1.0)
    sprite.runAction(action)
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    sprite.removeAllActions()
    let action2 = SKAction.moveToY(900, duration: 1.0)
    sprite.runAction(action2)
}
```

Comment: first thanks for responding if i put remove all actions after the action of rotating the sprite wont rotate and only the other action will executed maybe i didnt illuminate what i want exactly , i dont how to do it but i will tell what i want it to be , "when i touch the screen i want to create the object and rotate till i release my finger i want it to go up"